# pagination not working; keeps reloading Page 1

Tags: wordpress

I have a fairly simple loop to display 10 posts on a page. The pagination links are included at the bottom - but clicking the link just re-loads the page. The page load does not seem to see or honour the $paged variable.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php _s_paging_nav(); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What is `_s_paging_nav` from? Doesn't look like a native WP function.

Comment: @AdamHopkinson that was an example I got from another thread... didn't work either though...